# Como setar o local de instalação no ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no VS2012 usando o WPF, eu estou usando o próprio ClickOnce para instalar a aplicação, só que ele sempre instala nas pastas dos usuários, tipo:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GT??4KXX.PRJ\EGV???1G.??C\prin..tion_7???5a2?????74b6_0000.0002_1dae????89111c35

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu setar um caminho específico para a instalação da minha aplicação ou ao menos que ele instale no C:\Arquivos e Programas

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como mudar, o ClickOnce foi feito para ser assim, até porque ele foi feito para qualquer usuário do computador poder instalar o programa, mesmo não tendo permissões de administrador, salvo o caso do usuário não ter o .Net Framework instalado.

Se quer ter controle sobre onde o programa é instalado então precisa criar um instalador normal mesmo, seja o projeto de instalador incluído no VS.Net ou algum outro de terceiros como o InnoSetup.

Comment: Entendi, então não eu não tenho essa possibilidade de nenhuma maneira?

Comment: Com o uso do ClickOnce não